# Base64_decode a json value for form input

Tags: php, json, ajax, base64

I am trying to create an edit form that fetchs a person's data (mysql) upon it's selection via select box.

So far I am fetching it well using ajax, the thing is, some sensible data is encoded with base64, so i get the form input with the base64 encoded string inside the input. I would like to know if there is a way to decode the data. I've tried to find some awnsers but they don't work on this case and I get the undefinned errors.

Here is the function the ajax function:

```
<script>
function getManager(val){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../ajax/ajax_populate_managers.php",
        data: 'manager='+val,
        success: function(response){
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            if (result.response == true) {
                var data = result.rows;
                $("#managerName").val(data.managerName);
                $("#managerPhone").val(data.managerPhone); ->base64 encoded data that i want to decode
                $("#managerEmail").val(data.managerEMail); ->base64 encoded data that i want to decode
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use ATOB & BTOA.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Usage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Comment: I get a DOMException, but the only reference to this expcetions relates to " if the length of passed-in string is not a multiple of 4 ".

Answer (score 0):

You should use [atob and btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) for base64 encoding and decoding

https://codebrace.com/editor/b07f75ec4